# C# asp:ListBox hide vertical scrollbar

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

How to hide the vertical scroll bar of a Listbox that is present inside a div.

```
<div id="lstQueriesDiv" style="overflow-y: hidden !important; overflow-x: auto !important;
         Width: 650px; height:167px;" > 
 <asp:ListBox ID="lstQueries" runat="server" CssClass="cssLstQueries" Rows="9"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

css:

```
    .cssLstQueries{
    Width:auto;
    }
```

I want to hide the vertical scrollbar of the listbox not the the vertical scrollbar of the div.

Comment: Try with next solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22863151/717267

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Remove `OVERFLOW:auto`; from

```xml
<div id="lstQueriesDiv" style="OVERFLOW:auto; Width: 650px; height:167px;" >
```

because it's overwriting the CSS class where you have `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: when i removed the OVERFLOW:auto; the horizontal scroll bar disappeared.

Comment: i need the horizontal scroll bar of the div and to remove the vertical scroll bar of the listbox

Comment: so set overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:auto; like pranay_stacker said

Comment: <div id="lstQueriesDiv" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:auto; Width: 650px; height:167px;" > 
                          <asp:ListBox ID="lstQueries" runat="server" CssClass="cssLstQueries"  Rows="9" ></asp:ListBox>
                       </div>




.cssLstQueries{
Width:auto;
}


and still no horizontal scrollbar

Comment: The problem is that the vertical scrollbar of the listbox is visible .

Comment: <div id="lstQueriesDiv" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; Width: 650px; height:167px;" > 
                          <asp:ListBox ID="lstQueries" runat="server" CssClass="cssLstQueries"  Rows="9" ></asp:ListBox>
                       </div>



.cssLstQueries{
Width:auto;
overflow:hidden;
-ms-overflow-x: hidden;
-ms-overflow-y: hidden;
}

Comment: cssLstQueries is the css of the listbox and is not hiding the vertical scrollbar

Comment: I want to hide the vertical scrollbar of the listbox not the the vertical scrollbar of the div.

Answer (score 1):

set the scrollbars in your object properties